# Translate "This too shall pass"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I was trying to translate this famous motto.
Is the following correct?

> Hoc quoque effluet.

Do you think of a better translation?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_too_shall_pass

Answer (score 3):

I think it is rather a proverb (or idiom if you will), than a motto. I personally remember it since high school as "Solomon's Seal".

Nevertheless, here are some variants I have [stumbled upon](https://www.quora.com/Whats-an-accurate-translation-of-this-too-shall-pass-in-latin):

> Et hoc abibit

and another variant, which literally should mean "*these too shall pass*" (i.e. "*even this bad time will end one day*")

> Et haec abibunt

Comment: This looks like a very natural way to approach this. How would you feel about *praeterire*  instead of *abire* to pass by rather than go away?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I do not feel qualified enough to make this judgement. Since translations in my answer are by other people, I have simply found them and posted here.